# При нажатии на TreeItem<String> изменить данные в TableView<Object>

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

Есть `TreeView<String>` и таблица `TableView<Object>`. Хочу сделать так, чтобы по нажатию (мышкой) на один из `TreeItem<String>` менялись данные в таблице.

Comment: На `TreeView` добавьте `addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED...`. Задача данного `Handler` получить выделенный элемент `TreeView` и выполнить соответствующие действия.

Comment: Александр Савостьянов, спасибо, получилось. Изначально я добавлял `addEventHandler` прямо для `TreeItem` и результата не было. Не подскажете почему? (Возможно потому что не расширяет класс `Control`?). Есть еще один вопрос: каждый раз когда кликаешь на определенный `TreeItem` обработчик обрабатывает событие (и оно понятно). В моем случае, задача обработчика - достать данные из бд. Думаю будет очень не хорошо, если при каждом клике на один и тот же `TreeItem` обработчик будет выполнять sql-запрос. Не подскажете, как лучше это обойти?

Comment: `TreeItem` не является `Node` и поэтому он не может обрабатывать события такого рода. Эти события могут быть обработаны ячейками, если вы явно зададите `CellFactory`. Но в этом нет особого смысла в большинстве ситуаций. Для избежания дублирования действий можете использовать кэш (например, `Map`, где ключ некий `id` `TreeItem`, а значение - результат запроса)